# Problems during getting data from external JSON in D3.js

Tags: json

I'm trying to load some data from the external JSON file to put them into the tooltip, but something is going wrong and I can't figure it out. My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "results": [
      {

        "name": "First Candidate",
        "result": 52,
        "victory": "winner",
        "region": "First region",
        "constituencyName": "First constituency",
        "constituencyNumber": 1,
        "partyName": "Ruling party",
        "partyShort": "PR",
        "partyStatus": "Right"
      },
      {
        "name": "Second Candidate",
        "result": 48,
        "victory": "looser",
        "region": "First region",
        "constituencyName": "First constituency",
        "constituencyNumber": 1,
        "partyName": "Opposition party",
        "partyShort": "OP",
        "partyStatus": "Left"
      }
   ]
}
```

It's the part of my code where I'm trying to get the data:

```
d3.json("test_json.json", function(error, data) {
    dataViz(data.results);
});
```

Here is the full code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/v1rz2vfu/

Comment: test_json.json is not on path. Error: `status:404; statusText:"NOT FOUND";` Do this to see the error:  `d3.json("test_json.json", function(error, data) {
         console.log(error);
 //dataViz(data.results);
});`

Comment: you have to use the full address for the json `d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23920803/infographics/2016/2016.08.29_elections_results/my_files/test_json/test_json.json", function(error, data) {
 dataViz(data.results);
});`

Comment: Just one additional information: One doesn't have to use the full address on `d3.json`, it accepts relative paths as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full address for the json : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/v1rz2vfu/15/

```
d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23920803/infographics/2016/2016.08.29_elections_results/my_files/test_json/test_json.json", function(error, data) {
    dataViz(data.results);
});
```

Comment: `d3.json` accepts relative paths as well, as long as it's correct, of course.